# How to define selected value for jQuery UI combobox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here is the code - http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/k2J5v/8/. Once button is pressed, default value (`value="0"`) should be chosen there.

I've tried

```
$("#cbCity").val("0"); // cbCity - combobox
```

But it doesn't work. Looks like I also need to change the value of input element.

Such change should **not** call `select`.

Upd. I've also tried to do [the following](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/k2J5v/26/):

```
$("#cbCity").html('<option value="0" selected>Any city</option>');
$("#cbCity").val("0");
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: Do you need to make your ajax call every time someone clicks the drop down? Or are you fine with loading it once and using that data during the duration of their stay?

Comment: @Jackson, I think I can load list of most popular cities once, but surely I shoudn't load the whole list.

Comment: @LA Do you have a pretty big list? If so, maybe you could load it synchronously?

Comment: @Jackson, the list of all possible cities looks big for me :)

Comment: @LA that's a tough one :( It may help to use a cached server response, but there's other problems you might run into there. My knowledge is about capped out on that one. Let me know if there's anything else I can help out with!

Answer (score 9):

[Here's your huckleberry.](http://jsfiddle.net/k2J5v/80/)

What was *done*:

- Moved your code from the `_create` to the page. This way users don't have to wait for the data every time they click. The code happens once on page load and that's it. You may want to move this to a DOM Ready.
- Made the original `select` hidden by default so you don't see the jarring change of style to the `ui.combobox`.
- Changed how your `ui.combobox` items were laid out so that "Any City" is at the top.
- When you *click* `#showAnyCity` then both the custom cb and the original cb both reset. The combo selection menu is closed as well (in case it was open).

***Happy Coding***

Comment: voteup for thinking bigger than just the immediate problem, good overall recommendations for this situation!

Comment: Good solution, but .find(':first') will always return the first item, and not the selected one. My only change would be:
 `var sel_str = 'any';
$('.ui-autocomplete-input').val($("#cbCity").val(sel_str).find(":selected").val());`
in the case of `sel_str` being any value.
EDIT: hit enter instead of shift enter :(

Comment: @gusterlover6 it's been a while since I wrote this, but my understanding was that the "show Any City" button is just supposed to highlight the element "Any City" which is statically the first element. Hence the breakdown: `show` *Any City*

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I think there are two things going on:

1. You're not wireing up the click event to the correct object. You had `$("#toggle").click()` but you really want `$("#showAnyCity").click()`
2. When you change the select list item and your AJAX call comes back, you are not re-adding the 'Any city' and 'Other city' options. If there isn't an option with a value of "0", than `.val("0")` won't do anything. You either need to add them server side in the results that get sent back in the AJAX call or add them to the select list in the JavaScipt.

Comment: Re 1 - yeah, sorry, just copied the code incorrectly ;). Re 2 - will try that later, thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried option 2 with value="London" (server returns such value), but is doesn't work - http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/k2J5v/14/. And, I don't know how to add an option on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want I think so!

Now I have done with jquery UI combobox as you need it.

You need to add a function as mentioned below

```
autocomplete : function(value) {
    this.element.val(value);
    this.input.val(value);
}
```

And you need to call like this

```
$('#cbCity').combobox('autocomplete', 'Any city');
```

I have updated with this new one check out this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fa9Hs/62/